# How can I get source to use in GitHub?

Tags: reactjs, installation, clone

I need to clone this side or run it: https://securingsincity.github.io/react-ace/.

It is open source in https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace, but I have spent so much time and I can archive to run it in my local

How can I run it or install it in local?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to its repo: https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace

And clone it with:

`git clone https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace`

you can find the URL here:

[image]

Then you should install de node_modules for example with npm will be `npm install`

Comment: Thank you bro, after i install i do not how to run it